# Android Emulator not running on AMD Ryzen 2400G

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I tried to use the "Android Virtual Device Emulator" on my Windows-PC using a AMD Ryzen 2400G and Windows 10 Professional. I activated the Windows-Hypervisor-Platform, restarted my PC and Android Studio, but it still says "x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration". How can I install the hardware acceleration using an AMD Processor?

Comment: I needed to disable Hyper-V in Windows features.
And check that this value isoff: WindowsDefender ->Device Security->Core isolation -> Memory integrity

Answer (score 1):

In order to run the Android Emulator with an AMD processor you need to do the following, [according to Google](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html?m=1)

- AMD Processor - Recommended: AMD® Ryzen™ processors
- Android Studio 3.2 Beta or higher - download via Android Studio Preview page
- Android Emulator v27.3.8+ - download via Android Studio SDK Manager
- x86 Android Virtual Device (AVD)
- Windows 10 with April 2018 Update (version 1803)
- Enable "Windows Hypervisor Platform" via Windows Features: Search for *Turn Windows features on or off* and check this option, which is present in all Windows editions, including Home edition starting from version 1803. This term can be confused with Hyper-V, but they are different things. You only need to turn the former on in order to use the emulator.

I followed all these steps in my HP Envy X360 with AMD Ryzen 7 2700U and was still getting the "emulation currently requires hardware acceleration" error. What fixed it for me was turning on "Virtualization" in my BIOS settings. It may have another name in other BIOS systems, but apparently you need to turn the setting that allows virtualization on as a final step.

FYI, it's usable but laggy in my system (256 GB SSD + 8 GB RAM). I wouldn't use it for everyday work, only for some sort of emergency case. I'd suggest to stick to a physical device when possible, if you have similar specs.

Answer (score 1):

I had all the requirements listed by schv09, like good versions and virtualization and Windows Hypervisor Platform enabled, but Android Emulator did not work for me either with Ryzen 5 1600. **I updated Windows 10 from version 1803 to latest 1903, and now it works.** I can't tell what has changed.